# How to filter then calculate variance of filtered set?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this data sheet which contains these columns:

Age | Gender | Salary.

I'd like to filter these rows by age and gender and then calculate the sample variance of these rows(variance of salary, of course). What's the excel formula to achieve this?

I'm thinking of **VARA(FILTER(Array, condition))** but can't figure out what to write inside brackets because array contains irrelevant information. VARA needs the salary column only.  Any answer to this noob question would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: inside the parenthess would be a formula like `filter`

Comment: Like how? Could you write it for me? I'm so new to excel @gns100

Comment: Start with a google search for "excel formula filter". From there figure out how to filter on just one parameter like Gender, then add age. Finally wrap that formula with the `VARA()` you mentioned in your post.

Comment: @gns100 Thanks! I've clarified my question.

Comment: note that you may add to your question as you find part of a solution, and even write an answer yourself if you find something that fulfills your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple as VARA(FILTER(FILTER(yourArray, condition), binary-array-indicating-your-chosen-column).

First FILTER selects out your wanted rows. Second filter extracts the column as the array for VARA, which calculates the sample variance.